# Filtering objects by datetime field on MongoDB Atlas API returns ZERO (0) documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

We are trying out MongoDB atlas APIs for one of our projects. However, when we try to filter the data based on a datetime field, it returns zero documents.

API: https://data.mongodb-api.com/app/data-dfmng/endpoint/data/beta/action/find

METHOD: POST

PAYLOAD:

```
{
    "collection": "trade",
    "database": "sm",
    "dataSource": "Cluster0",
    "filter": {
        "DATE1": "2022-06-02T00:00:00Z"
    },    
    "sort": {
        "SYMBOL": -1
    },
    "projection": {
        "DATE1": 1,
        "SYMBOL": 1,
        "AVG_PRICE": 1
    }
}
```

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Date should be in extended JSON format https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/api/data-api/#date Unix timestamp in millis for 2022-06-02T00:00:00Z is 1654128000000 :

```
"filter": {
    "DATE1": {"$date": {"$numberLong": "1654128000000"}}
},
```